# How do i set a text size of a textbox deppending what option is chosen in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-entry

```
global my_frame
my_frame = Frame(tab2, bg="white")
my_frame.place(relwidth= 0.81, relheight= 0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1,)

text_scroll = Scrollbar(my_frame)
text_scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
```

the text entry

```
global textbox
textbox = Text(my_frame,undo=True,font=12, yscrollcommand=text_scroll.set)
textbox.place(relwidth= 0.985, relheight= 1, relx=0, rely=0)

text_scroll.config(command=textbox.yview)
```

the dropdown menu i want to be able to select the font

```
clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set(12)

drop = OptionMenu(tab2,clicked, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14)
drop.pack()
```

My problem is i dont know how to say to the text size to set deppending on what number the user did select. Please help.

Comment: Use `clicked.trace("w", callback)` and in the `callback` function use `clicked.get()` to get what is in the `OptionMenu`. After that you can just use `textbox.config(font=<new font>)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def callback(*args):
    new_font_size = int_var.get()
    text_widget.config(font=("", new_font_size))

root = tk.Tk()

text_widget = tk.Text(root, font=("", 12))
text_widget.pack()

int_var = tk.IntVar(root)
int_var.trace("w", callback)
drop = tk.OptionMenu(root, int_var, *range(1, 15))
drop.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I change the variable from `tk.StringVar` to `tk.IntVar` because we are dealing with `int`s. Also the `font` argument should be a tuple like this: `("<font family name>", <font size>)`.

I am tracing what the `int_var` value is and updating the `text_widget` accordingly.